# "Format not supported Error" While Playing youtube video within iphone application

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, youtube, youtube-api

I need to fetch the playlist for specific username.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/%@/playlists?alt=json&v=2&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-profile",strUserName];
```

I use the above URl to fetch the JSON feeds for the username specified. Now when I parse this I get a list of playlist under the key "entry" which happens to be the array of playlist publicly available. To fetch all videos in specific playlist I again use a formatted URL like

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/%@?alt=json&v=2",currentPlayList.strPlayListId];
```

where currentPlayList.strPlayListId is actually the playlist id provided by youtube. The actual problem is to show the youtube video on iphone without exiting the application so I have used this [method](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application)

Now passing the video ID (fetched from the playlist data as JSON) in URL

```
NSString* mediaURL =    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@",video.strMediaId];
```

where **video.strMediaId** is the video id of the video I wish to play results in Error of "**This movie format is not supported**" and it happens for all the videos.I have tried using all the links that are fetched under video details from youtube. There are similar [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315609/movie-format-not-supported-on-iphone-with-youtube-player-in-a-webview) post for this. Any help/comments will be appreciated to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has nothing to do with the iPhone. When people post videos to YouTube they have to allow it to be viewed on mobile devices. If they don't you'll get that message.

You can also get that message if there was a loss of signal or something similar while downloading the video. On those cases, rerunning the video usually works after a few tries.

Also, if the video has been recently uploaded, and the mobile version hasn't been processed yet, you'll get that message.

The only thing I can suggest is to make sure you have a strong, fast WiFi connection and see if the problem still manifests itself.

Comment: I have tried playing close to 20+ different videos under various names and only One out of those 20 worked, I could play all these in native Youtube application on iphone. Any Clue for that ?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/message/13238826?messageID=13238826#13238826 Not sure this is your problem, but its worth giving it a shot?

Comment: Also, have you tried it on a lot of devices? Most of the time this happens its on a 3G or a 3GS from what I've seen.

Comment: Right now I am using iPhone4 running iOS 4.3.3 using WiFi. But I can try it on iPod and 3GS as well.